# Maven Aggregated site generation

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

I have a maven based project. There are four different projects like shown in the structure below. Each main project and the subprojects have their own pom.xml files.

```
ProjectA
    |
    --------subProjects     
ProjectB  
   |
   --------subprojects
ProjectC    
   |
   --------subProjects
ProjectD
   |
    -------subprojects
```

I am running `mvn site` on `ProjectC` which is dependent on `ProjectB` which is inter-dependent on `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`

So when i run maven site all the `test results` for all these projects get created `individually`. What I would also like to do is to create a `aggregation` of all the test results in these projects and sub-projects and show it in `one place`.

So is it possible with maven site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit different approach would be to see test results in specialized servers like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) or [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/). This way no need to modify existing projects.

See running examples at https://builds.apache.org/ and https://analysis.apache.org/

Two screenshot from Sonar:
[image: Test results]

[Result by module and package](https://analysis.apache.org/drilldown/measures/20341?metric=test_success_density&rids%5B%5D=28556)
[image: Test results by module & package]

For Jenkins there is [Dashboard View Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There are two options:

1. "[You can do this by setting project.build.directory on all of your projects to a common folder.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6522305/34088)"
2. You can add extra directories to the `maven-surefire-report-plugin` by adding an `reportsDirectories` element with `reportsDirectory` children ([documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-mojo.html)).

So this should work:

```
<reportsDirectories>
    <reportsDirectory>../ProjectA/target/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
    <reportsDirectory>../ProjectA/module1/target/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
    ...
</reportsDirectories>
```

Comment: Should this be added only to the parent pom?

Comment: #1 can be added just to the parent pom, the second can't be because these settings would be used for each module. But then, I'd create a completely new project for the second approach which just aggregates test results.